# How to add table to database inventory in sqlplus oracle 12c

Tags: oracle-12c, installation, sqlplus

**Problems**

**How to create database Inventory database and inside it table Items in sqlplus
oracle 12c .**
**Details**

Im beginner on Oracle 12c release
 i setup oracle and i create database Inventory

**Now how to add table items to database Inventory**

i can create table but how to create it inside database Inventorty
this actually what i need

```
Create table Items
(
itemno number(4) not null,
itemname varchar2(40) not null
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You either login as user Inventory before running the DDL, or you create the table by specifying the Schema like

```
create table Inventory.Items
( ... );
```